# Сохранение открытых сайтов

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Хочу реализовать программу для отслеживания на компьютере открытых сайтов. Чтобы, когда пользователь открывал какой-нибудь сайт, он сохранялся в бд. Как узнать адрес сайта?